# Java app printing logging related error messages to stdout

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

When I run my java application, it prints to standard output the following two lines:

```
Bad level value for property: .level
Bad level value for property: java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level
```

This appears to be output from java.util.logging (?)

However in my project, I'm using log4j and slf4j. As far as I know, I'm not directly using java.util.logging.

The logging itself is working correctly - my logging properties file is read, and the log output is directed to an output file. I'm just curious to understand the source of these error messages.

These messages are output when I run on a paricular host (which is running CentOS 6.2). When I run the same program on a MacBook, I do not see the errors.

Any suggestions for what I can do to debug this further would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that even if one doesn't use java.util.logging the logging.properties (at least $PATH_TO_JAVA/jre/lib/logging.properties ) is parsed, and if something is set wrong, java complains. I had set '.level = DEBUG', but DEBUG is not an allowed value.

Comment: What are the allowed values?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/data_processing_bdd/src/rdp_logging_config.html Here are the levels: SEWERE WARNING INFO CONFIG FINE FINER FINEST ALL